# setup for navigation buttons

Tags: css, css-float

I am using jquery tools scrollable plugin with Navigator plugin for navigation buttons.

everything is working great it just a matter of positioning.

right now i have to us absolute positioning for the navigation buttons:

```
.navi {
    width: auto;
    height:13px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 35px;
    top: 10px;
}

.navi a {
    width:8px;
    height:8px;
    float:right;
    margin:3px;
    background: url(../img/navigator.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
    display:block;
    font-size:1px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

I need to have the anchors floating right because they will grow dynamically and in the design the are aligned on the right edge and grow out to the left side.

The problem with that, the plugin will make the anchor to the far right the first one.  I need the first anchor on the left side to be the first one and iterate to the right.

currently the html looks like this

```
<div class="navi">
  <a></a>
  <a></a>
  <a class="active"></a>
</div>
```

with them floating right.

I need them to float right but render like this:

```
<div class="navi">
  <a class="active"></a>
  <a></a>
  <a></a>
</div>
```

I'm using this plugin [Jquery Tools Navigator](http://flowplayer.org/tools/scrollable/navigator.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default functionality of `float:right;` is to display the first element far right and the following elements will line up from right to left. If you want them to be displayed from left to right you would have to use `float: left;`. If floating left is not working for you you would have to rearrange the order of the images.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a CSS issue - nothing to do with jquery, and certainly not the C# 'float' tag!

I presume this image 'navigator.png' is 20x20px, so you will have to use a block element on the .navi a liks to be able to set the size. In that case, you will have to use float: left on .navi a, and then change .navi width: auto to a specified size (3 a tags = 3 x (8+6) = 42 - that's the width+margin). This then lets you enter some text in the  tags which you can hide using .navi a text-indent:-9999px.

The alternative is to just hack it a bit using some padding. Personally, I'd use the first solution. Let me know if you need clarification with the CSS code.